# Unity SignReleaseBundle Failed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build, keystore

I am trying to build my Unity Project to Android but I keep getting the same Error when the build arrives at the gradle build. The error says that the task: signReleaseBundle failed. I am currently using Unity 2018.4.13f1. I was able to build it without any problems a few times but suddenly the next day, I tried to make a Update because I discovered a pretty bad bug, but it was then it stop working and I start receiving the error messages.

The full error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
D:\Programme\Unity Hub\2018.4.8f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "D:\Programme\Unity Hub\2018.4.8f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':signReleaseBundle'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 :
  jarsigner: key associated with artyon not a private key


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
]
stdout[

> Configure project :
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :extractProguardFiles
> Task :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processReleaseManifest
> Task :bundleReleaseResources
> Task :mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processReleaseResources
> Task :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE

> Task :transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease
R8 is the new Android code shrinker. If you experience any issues, please file a bug at
https://issuetracker.google.com, using 'Shrinker (R8)' as component name. You can
disable R8 by updating gradle.properties with 'android.enableR8=false'.
Current version is: 1.4.77 (build b74371231cb896b02f83285efb055b7c00ff64d8 from go/r8bot (luci-r8-ci-archive-0-eqqf)).


> Task :mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildReleasePreBundle
> Task :collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :configureReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :packageReleaseBundle
> Task :validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :signingConfigWriterRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :signReleaseBundle FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
29 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 20 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <7ba523db75d04b42a8b9a4dd9587e521>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <7ba523db75d04b42a8b9a4dd9587e521>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <7ba523db75d04b42a8b9a4dd9587e521>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <7ba523db75d04b42a8b9a4dd9587e521>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <7ba523db75d04b42a8b9a4dd9587e521>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <7ba523db75d04b42a8b9a4dd9587e521>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <7ba523db75d04b42a8b9a4dd9587e521>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <7ba523db75d04b42a8b9a4dd9587e521>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You're making a build for Android, have you signed your bundle and provided your passwords before running the build machine? If not, that's the main reason it fails.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your passwords may be incorrect when you enter them on build settings.
check your passwords then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when I built my own game!!! But I had already succeeded in building several times!!!

I tried changing the version of gradle, and edit   AndroidManifest file , erasing all the plugins and reinserting them, but there is no sign that  the error will be cured.

I thought it was a mistake, but when I re-entered the Keystore password and built it without error !!!

The error I struggled with for three days was due to the wrong Keystore password ...

Anyway, I'm happy that the error was fixed. Please be careful about the wrong password of Keystore so as not to make such a terrible mistake ...

I used Unity 2019.4.28f1 in MacBook Pro

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution: upgrade plugin